# Can't read downloaded files to actual android phone (Android 10) and crashes on a third party emulator. But working in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am new to android development and I need help please.

I have a working/running project in Android Studio. But after installing it to my phone, the next activity is not showing or nothing happens when I click on the button. And on a third party emulator, the app doesn't open at all.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.czx.movplex">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    tools:targetApi="31">

    <activity android:name=".Act3"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".login"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

login.java

```
package com.czx.movplex;
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText etUserName, etPassword;
private Button btLogin;
private TextView tvText, tvText2, tvText3;

private String user_path = "Working URL HERE";
private String pass_path = "Working URL HERE";
private URL url = null;
private  URL url2 = null;
private String user_filename;
private String pass_filename;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    initViews();
    btLogin.setEnabled(false);
    df(user_filename, url);
    df(pass_filename, url2);
    (new Handler()).postDelayed(() -> {
        try {
            setListeners();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, 5000);
}

private void initViews() {

    etUserName = findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btLogin = findViewById(R.id.btLogin);
    tvText = findViewById(R.id.tvText);
    tvText2 = findViewById(R.id.tvText2);
    tvText3 = findViewById(R.id.tvText3);

    try {
        url = new URL(user_path);
        url2 = new URL(pass_path);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    user_filename = url.getPath();
    user_filename = user_filename.substring(user_filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    pass_filename = url2.getPath();
    pass_filename = pass_filename.substring(pass_filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

}

private void df(String fn, URL url) {
    File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)+"/" + fn);
    if(file.exists())
        Toast.makeText(this, "File existed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url + ""));
        request.setTitle(fn);
        request.setMimeType("application/text");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, fn);
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);

    }
}

private void setListeners() throws IOException {

    String[] fragment;
    String[] users = getData(user_filename);
    String[] pwds = getData(pass_filename);

    btLogin.setEnabled(true);
    btLogin.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if(etUserName.getText().toString().matches("") || etPassword.getText().toString().matches("")){
            tvText.setText("Please type your username and/or password.");
            etUserName.setText("");
            etPassword.setText("");
            return;
        }

        String username, pwd = "";
        username = etUserName.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        pwd = etPassword.getText().toString();

        for(int i = 0; users.length > i; i++) {
            if (username.equals(users[i].toLowerCase())) {
                if(pwd.equals(pwds[i])){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Valid User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    toNextAct();
                }
                //break;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

}

private void toNextAct() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, Act3.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private String[] getData(String filename) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fin = null;
    int ch;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String text = "";
    String[] fragments = new String[0];
    try{
        fin = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)+"/"+filename);
        while((ch = fin.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char)ch);
        }
        text = sb.toString();
        fragments = text.split(";");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found" + e);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception while reading file " + ioe);
    }
    finally {
        // close the stream using close method
        try {
            if (fin != null) {
                fin.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error while closing stream: " + ioe);
        }
    }
    return fragments;
}
```

}

Act3.java

```
public class Act3 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act3);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    return;
}
}
```

bundle.gradle(.app)

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'}android {
compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.czx.movplex"
    minSdk 23
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

// Glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.2'
}
```

All reds from Logcat:

[image]

Update

The problem has something to do with this part in login.java:

```
for(int i = 0; users.length > i; i++) {
        if (username.equals(users[i].toLowerCase())) {
            if(pwd.equals(pwds[i])){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Valid User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                toNextAct();
            }
            //break;
        }
    }
```

It is not matching the username and password using my device while in Android Studio, it works perfectly. So I guess it has something to do with permission on my device.

My phone OS is Android 10.

The actual URL part are not included on the posted code for login.java. I will greatly appreciate your help thank you.

Comment: you didn't use else condition if password doesn't match, may be your entering wrong password. Because there is no command for wrong password

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That project is working perfectly in Android studio even without the "else" part yet. I'm typing the correct username and password to the actual phone but nothing happens.

Comment: for authentication your using local data storage or any server ?

Comment: Thank you for asking that. local data storage. The project is downloading something from a server and do the authentication base from that downloaded file. Can't include some sensitive code sorry for that. But that is what is happening.

Comment: Or does it have anything to do with the OS version? I believe I am targeting lollipop and up.

Comment: when your trying to run in real device some of your function doesn't working that's why system couldn't recognize authenticated data and doesn't working.

Comment: Sometimes some function doesnt working if policy doesnt meet. In real device some restrictions may be

Comment: Is your Toast appearing? If not then you're not matching a username and password. It's probably worth putting a breakpoint in your checking function and then debugging the app, so you can step through and look at exactly what's happening (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug if you're not familiar)

Comment: I see let me re-check my functions and I'll try debugging by breakpoint now. Meanwhile kindly check if there are still some irregularities on the other parts of the codes/file. My authentication process is kinda weird but bare with me. I am trying a different approach as part of a demonstration.

Comment: Oh yeah by the way Kayes Fahim, the toast is not showing even after typing in the correct username and password.

Comment: I am sorry. I mean Cactustictacs.

Comment: @cactustictacs The problem is that, it is working perfectly in Android Studio. Even the toast for valid user then going to the next activity.

Comment: @cactustictacs If it has something to do with my actual device then, what does it block?

Comment: @cactustictacs Done debugging by breakpoint but it is really working as expected from  Android Studio. So I guess yeah It has something to do with my device. Now I need to know what is it that my device is blocking?

Comment: you should try with another device

Comment: I only have one device running Android. Can I use a third party emulator? @KayesFahim

Comment: definately If You have posted all of your code may be then we can do something

Comment: If the toast isn't showing, then it's not matching a username and password, because the Toast happens when it does. So either there's no matching username in `users`, no matching password in `pwds`, or they're mixed up so the username at `users[i]` doesn't correspond to the password stored in `pwds[i]`. You haven't shown how you're getting that data so we don't know if you're storing it correctly, or if it's being fetched at all on that device. You need to debug it (on the device) so you can look at the contents of `users` and `pwds` and see if the match *should* work, or if there's a problem

Comment: Let me run the app to a third party emulator first. Then, after than I'll post the complete code of the  login.java. @KayesFahim

Comment: @cactustictacs That is not the case from Android Studio. From the Android Studio it is working as expected. Matching the username and password is working as well.

Comment: @cactustictacs I will post the complete code for the login.java in a bit.

Comment: I run the app to a third party emulator called LDPlayer and the app crashes. @KayesFahim

Comment: Yes the fact it works on your emulator (I assume that's what you mean by "from Android Studio") shows your code's *logic* works fine - so it's probably an issue with the *data* **on your device** where the match is failing. Your code is simple (match lowercased usernames, match passwords) and you've proven it works, so the problem is *there's no match in your username/password data*. You said your project "downloads something from a server" so that's probably where your problem is and you need to debug it *on the device where it's failing* to see why it's failing- it's very likely a data issue

Comment: Please updated your code and post all code so that we can check and give a solution.

Comment: There's no reason to post any more code - it's a button click listener that takes the contents of two text boxes and looks for a match at the same index in two arrays or whatever. Do you get the error when a text field is empty? If so then the click listener works. The matching logic works on the emulator, and just looking at it there's no obvious problem with it. The issue is that there's no match in the data. And the OP can't show us the data, so there's not much else we can do except tell them to look there because that's where the problem is

Comment: @KayesFahim Updated the login.java code. Bare with it. It might not be the standard approach. Just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @cactustictacs Yes I am getting the toast for empty text field. All other things are working on my actual device, It is just that when I type in the correct username and password nothing happens. By the way, I already posted the complete code for login.java except for the imports part. I hope that might help.

Comment: From my Android Studio everything are working. To my actual device what doesn't work is the next activity when I type in the correct user and pass. And to a third party emulator the app crashes.

Comment: can you send the error log when you running activity

Comment: @cactustictacs And also the downloading part is working on my device. I can see the files downloaded in the "Documents". You can check my updated code.

Comment: @KayesFahim From Android Studio? No errors from the log. All are working perfectly in Android Studio.

Comment: check carefully

Comment: @KayesFahim Can I send the logcat instead?

Comment: yes send the full logcat or any red

Comment: @KayesFahim Alright let me re-run the app and provide all that is in red from logcat.

Comment: @KayesFahim by the way is there a way to filter logcat to show just all the things in red?

Comment: Alright this is what I did. I run the app in Android Studio. Type in the correct username and password and click login then it successfully open the next activity. But I will update my post to include all the reds from the logcat.

Comment: @KayesFahim Kindly check the logcat on my post. Thank you.

Comment: @cactustictacs You are right it has something to do with matching the username and password from my device. When I jump into next activity without matching the user and pass I can easily go to the next act. So my question now is, what modification I should need for the app work for both Android studio and my actual device?

Comment: I keep telling ya, the problem is your `users` and `pwds` data. It obviously doesn't contain what you're expecting. You could confirm this and look at the data by setting a  breakpoint and debugging the app on the device where it's failing. At a guess, you're failing to read your downloaded files since you're on Android 10 and that limits access to external storage: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage in which case you'd need to find another way to download your files, e.g. to your app's private storage (which seems like a better place for a file full of logins)

Comment: @cactustictacs yeah it is clear to me now. The app is failing to to read the downloaded files. But honestly since I am new to android development I am still limited to the things I can do. I guess I need to further study this page you provided developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage. Actually I downloaded the files to documents since it is only for demonstration but for official app it will definitely in the private storage. If you have code that will suite this project that would help me more.

Comment: @cactustictacs May I ask? Is it possible to download the files and save its content to internal storage? I know how to read files from internal storage but I don't know how to saved the downloaded files to internal storage.

Comment: `From my Android Studio everything are working` ? What do you mean by that? Apps run on a device or an emulator. Not on or in Android Studio.

Comment: And please post logcat as text.

Comment: @blackapps I mean running the project/app from Android Studio to it's built-in emulator. I thought that is understandable from one android developers to another. So I run the app in Android Studio (IDE) and it is working. I created an apk from Android Studio and install that to my android phone and it cannot read the downloaded files from Documents.

Comment: `So I run the app in Android Studio (IDE)`. Bad talking of an Android developer. Not in AS but in an emulator. Further you should tell who or which app downloaded the files to Documents directory.

Comment: @blackapps As I mentioned I am new to android development. Technically and maybe grammatically what I am saying are incorrect. That is why I am putting the necessary codes to make my point clear. But I believe there are things that are obvious and understandable from majority of the developers here. If you are going to help me correct the terms and proper way to say or write things, I appreciate that. However, I need help to make my project work.